# How can I use the AtTask API to Upload a File using C#

Tags: c#, api, upload, attask

I am using a modified version of the C# API Example to add tasks to an existing Workfront (AtTask) Task. I would also like to upload and download file attachments.

It appears from the documentation that uploading is a two-step process, step 1 upload the file and step 2 attach the uploaded file to the task. I understand somewhat how to do the second step - post a JSON token with the file name, the handle (from the upload), object type (TASK), object ID, and currentVersion. What I don't understand is step 1, the actual uploading of the file.

I am creating a PDF file that needs to be attached to the task. Once the task is completed, a new document will be added that I need to download.

Does anyone have any C# code for performing either the upload or the download?

Here is my code so far:

```
public JToken DoUpload(string path, string opportunityID, string description, params string[] parameters)
{
    List<string> list = parameters.ToList();

    if (!path.StartsWith("/"))
    {
    path = "/" + path;
    }
    string fullUrl = url + path + ToQueryString(parameters);
    string boundary = "------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

    WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateDefault(new Uri(fullUrl));
    request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
    request.Method = "POST";

    using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\" filename=\"{1}\"",  "uploadedFile", "RFQ" + opportunityID + ".html"));
        writer.WriteLine("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        writer.WriteLine();
        writer.WriteLine(description);

        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            return ReadResponse(responseStream);
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string HttpUploadFile(string url, string filename, byte[] file, string paramName, string contentType, NameValueCollection nvc)
{
        string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        wr.Method = "POST";
        wr.KeepAlive = true;
        wr.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();

        string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}";
        foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
        {
            rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
            string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, key, nvc[key]);
            byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
            rs.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);
        }
        rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

        string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
        string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, paramName, filename, contentType);
        byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
        rs.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

                    rs.Write(file, 0, file.Length);

        byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
        rs.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);
        rs.Close();

        WebResponse wresp = null;
        string ret = null;
        try
        {
            wresp = wr.GetResponse();
            Stream stream2 = wresp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);

            ret = reader2.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (wresp != null)
            {
                wresp.Close();
                wresp = null;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            wr = null;
        }

        return ret;
}
```

```
JToken ret = HttpUploadFile("/upload", file_name, file_bytes, "uploadedFile", "", new NameValueCollection());
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to get a handel, that is done just like any other api call you do to POST /attask/api/upload, this is where you include the file, it will be uploaded to a temp folder at Workfront(AtTask), Workfront will return the handel, then you do a second step to update the task incldue the handel and the file will be posted to it.

For more reference check out https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/ and https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/code-samples/

Comment: Thanks, Jim. I have read all the documentation, unfortunately the documentation regarding uploading files is very sparse, i.e, "Do a POST/attask/api/upload" - with no details on how to actually perform the upload. I have written some code, but have been successful only in generating 400 errors.